# How to put objects in a std::map?

Tags: c++, object, dictionary

Trying to figure out how to place objects in a map where the author is the key but can't seem to find how to do it.

heres my class object with a constructor

```
class Book
{ 
public:
string title = "";
string author = "";
int ISBN = 0;

Book(string t, string a, int num) 
{ 
    title = t; 
    author = a; 
    ISBN = num;
    if (ISBN < 1000 || ISBN > 9999)
        throw ("Invalid ISBN");
    assert(ISBN > 1000 || ISBN < 9999);
}
};
```

and here is the vector and the map

```
    vector <Book> books;
try
{
    Book book1("a", "Jim John", 1001);
    books.push_back(book1);
    Book book2("b", "Jim John", 1002);
    books.push_back(book2);
    Book book3("c", "Billy Bill", 1003);
    books.push_back(book3);
    Book book4("d", "Greg Lumburge", 1004);
    books.push_back(book4);
    Book book5("e", "Dallas Orange", 1005);
    books.push_back(book5);
    Book book6("f", "Old McDonald", 1006);
    books.push_back(book6);
}
catch (char*e)
{ 
    cout << "invalid ISBN" << endl; 
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

    map<string, Book> authorMap;

for (auto x : authorMap)
    cout << x.first<< " : "<< x.second << endl;
```

Comment: So, what is the problem with your code?

Comment: nothing yet until i try to populate it with my vector, starts saying that it cant match [] if I try (for (Book b : books){++authorMap[b];} )

Comment: Key has to be unique (c.f. "Jim John"). Otherwise, consider std::multimap. Also, [] operator takes the key type as argument (string type in your case, not Book).

Comment: Review multimap and unordered map containers to understand which container best suits your design requirements.  Both containers allow having duplicate keys with different value elements.  A map does not allow this.  Reference pages: [std::multimap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) and [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Insert API like this.

```
authorMap.insert ( "Dallas Orange",book5);

authorMap.insert ( "Jim John", Book ("a", "Jim John", 1001));
```

and you can use Iterators for accessing Book objects using author and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the documentation for map:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/

For your use case, you could do:

```
std::map<string,Book> authorMap;
Book book("a", "Jim John", 1001);
authorMap.insert ( std::pair<string,Book>(book.author,Book) );
```

Comment: -1: link-only answers with no supporting explanation are not very helpful and should be posted as comments, at most.

Comment: i tried something like this, just couldn't remember exactly what it looked like. I got no operator overload error on Insert

Comment: `pair<string,Book>` cannot go in `map<char,int>`

Comment: What exactly did you try? Can you update your question to reflect what you have already attempted? I wrote this answer assuming you had not even tried to insert something.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to fill the map from a vector. You can do this by

```
for_each(books.begin(), books.end(), [&authorMap] (Book & b) { authorMap[b.author]=b; } );
```

Don't forget ´#include < algorithm>´ though.

If you are new to lambdas (or are not using C++11), this is the same thing as

```
for(vector<Book>::const_iterator it = books.begin(); it!=books.end(); ++it)
{
    authorMap[it->author] = *it;
}
```

I should also point out that your solution will be problematic in case one author has written more than one book.

Comment: For the first or second snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Map is a collection of pairs. So in order to insert something into the map, it has to be first made into a pair. See the below example:

```
std::map<char, int> charIntMap;
std::pair<char, int> charIntPair('a', 65);

charIntMap.insert(charIntMap.end(), charIntPair);
charIntMap.insert(charIntMap.end(), std::pair<char, int>('b', 66));
```

now, another way to insert something into the map, is to take advantage of the [] operator. Here is what it can look like:

```
charIntMap['c'] = 67;
```